# I got error when hit back button

Tags: magento-1.9, product, reports

When I open a specific product it loads fine, but if I hit the browser back button, I get an error. I have no idea why this happens or where start to  check.

This happens always after loading that particular product first, and I got the error only in the homepage. Other pages always works fine.

In report, the error is:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:96:"SELECT `e`.* FROM `catalog_category_entity` AS `e` WHERE (`e`.`entity_type_id` = '3') AND (())

";i:1;s:4757:"0 /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
1 /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
2 /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
3 /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `e`.* FR...', Array)
4 /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `e`.* FR...', Array)
5 /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(737): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SELECT `e`.* FR...', Array)
6 /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(740): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll('SELECT `e`.* FR...', Array)
7 /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(1046): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_fetchAll('SELECT `e`.* FR...')
8 /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(871): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->_loadEntities(false, false)
9 /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Collection.php(225): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->load(false, false)
10 /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(741): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Collection->load()
11 /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/app/design/frontend/xr/default/template/aydus/page/html/ymal_products.phtml(73): Varien_Data_Collection->getIterator()
12 /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/usr/local/apac...')
13 /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/xr/def...')
14 /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
15 /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Reports/Block/Product/Viewed.php(82): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
16 /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(923): Mage_Reports_Block_Product_Viewed->_toHtml()
17 /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
18 /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(923): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
19 /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(641): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
20 /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(585): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
21 /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/app/design/frontend/xr/default/template/page/1column.phtml(57): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
22 /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/usr/local/apac...')
23 /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/xr/def...')
24 /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
25 /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(923): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
26 /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
27 /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
28 /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(137): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
29 /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
30 /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
31 /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
32 /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
33 /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
34 /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
35 /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
36 /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/index.php(106): Mage::run('', 'store')
37 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:2:"xr";}
```